# Recursion confusion

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am writing a function according to the following guidelines:

Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, beginning at the start index, such that the group sums to the given target? However, with the additional constraint that all 6's must be chosen. (No loops needed.)

```
groupSum6(0, {5, 6, 2}, 8) → true
groupSum6(0, {5, 6, 2}, 9) → false
groupSum6(0, {5, 6, 2}, 7) → false
```

This is the solution:

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (start == nums.length) {
        if (target == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (nums[start] == 6) {
        return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]);
    }
    if (groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) {
        return true;
    }
    return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target);
}
```

I am a little confused about why this works. I understand how it adds 6s, but where are the other numbers tested to see if they will add up to the target after the 6s have been added? Where are other non-6 numbers added?

Comment: What do you think `target - nums[start]` does?

Comment: You start out with a number `target`, each time you progress to the next element of the array you subtract the current element, and if you reach `0` then you've found a combination of numbers that the subtraction resulted in `0`, meaning adding the numbers together would have given the number.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this works is that the recursive call always checks to see if the number at the current index is a 6 and subtracts that from the target.  So the order of evaluation is:

1)

```
if (start == nums.length) {
    if (target == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check to see if the passed index is the length of the array (so this would mean the index is BEYOND the bounds of the array - the last index of the array would be nums[nums.length - 1] ).  If yes, AND if the target is 0, return true.  Otherwise return false, because there are no more values to check

2)
    if (nums[start] == 6) {
        return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]);
    }

Check if the number at the index is 6.  If it is, subtract 6 from the target, add one to the index, and check the remaining values.

3) Otherwise...

```
if (groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) {
    return true;
}
```

Evaluate if the rest of the array works to add up to the target.  If it does return true.  The key is to notice that this step will always happen AFTER we check if the value is a 6.  Essentially here you are looking for a solution that COUNTS the number in the start index.  If a solution is found we can end.  If no solution is found using the number at num[start], then we go on to:

4)

```
return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target);
```

Checking for a solution that exists when we DON'T use the number at num[start].

The key is that each time the recursive call is made the check for a 6 is done first ( assuming you aren't beyond the bounds of the array).

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But after recursing again, where is it possible to subtract a number that IS NOT a 6? The only instance where nums[start] is subtracted is after the check that nums[start] is a 6...

Comment: It does that inside the if statement: if(groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target-nums[start])    --- here it is looking for a solution that uses the current number

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to test all the possible subarray options, something like "what happen if i get next element?" and...  "what happen if i don't?".

So, for any element in the array your are making two recursive calls (two options, take it or not) and... if one of them is OK the solution is reached (so return true).

In the next recursive call you pick the number, so you call with the next index element (start+1) and substract the picked number from the target (imagine your target is 8 and the current element is 2... the recursive call is to check the next numbers with target 8-2= 6).

```
if (groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) {
        return true;
    }
```

The next recursive call is the same but you don't pick the current number so... target will be the same (in the previous example you will check the next number with target 8);

```
 return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target);
```

And... here it comes the 6 restriction... if you find a 6 then you have no more options than to pick the number so... you put that condition first (and in this scenario there is only one call because you have no options):

```
if (nums[start] == 6) {
        return groupSum6(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]);
    }
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But after recursing again, where is it possible to subtract a number that IS NOT a 6? The only instance where nums[start] is subtracted is after the check that nums[start] is a 6...

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar as previous question:

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if (target == 0) return true;
  if (start >= nums.length) return false;
  if (nums[start] == 6)
    return groupSum6(start+1, nums, target-nums[start]);
  return groupSum6(start+1, nums, target-nums[start]) || groupSum6(start+1, nums, target);
}
```

But it failed in 3 test cases
`groupSum6(0, [1, 6, 2, 6, 4], 9)`
`groupSum6(0, [3, 2, 4, 6], 3)`
`groupSum6(0, [5, 2, 4, 6], 9)` ,
so I had to replace the base condition as the above one

```
if (start == nums.length) {
  if (target == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I realized that the `start == nums.length` is necessary since there could be the possibility of more 6 in array, if its not the end of array and we have not included it but got the target.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this check if the number is 6 and then decide to skip it

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
//exit condition and if target becomes 0
if(start >= nums.length) return (target ==0);

// subtracting the number at start from target and make a recursive //call to groupSum6
if(groupSum6(start+1 , nums  , target - nums[start])) return true;
//check if the number at start is 6 or not then decide to skip it
if(nums[start] != 6  && groupSum6(start+1 , nums , target)) return true;
//if target does not becomes 0
return false;  
}
```